# How can I work on the same code with my friend in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

I and my friend want to create a website. We're using Vs code. How we can work on the same code in vs code? I'm looking for something that lets me edit on the code at any time I want and the same thing for him.

Comment: [GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 2):

### ***Use GitHub***

GitHub is a development platform inspired by the way you work. From open source to business, you can host and review code, manage projects, and build software alongside 50 million developers.

Github is a web-based platform used for version control. ***Git simplifies the process of working with other people and makes it easy to collaborate on projects.*** Team members can work on files and easily merge their changes.
You should definitely make your account on github as a developer as it helps alot.

Check it out here: https://github.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/. Once you are done doing your code you have to upload it on [github](https://github.com). Same as your friend can do. And the important thing is you can see/undo your previous code if you do anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinionated question and answer, but since you are using VsCode, I would recommend Microsoft's [Live Share](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/) . Since Microsoft is the creator of VsCode, I would guess this is going to be your best option to stay within the editor.

> Visual Studio Live Share enables you to collaboratively edit and debug with others in real time, regardless what programming languages you're using or app types you're building. It allows you to instantly (and securely) share your current project, and then as needed, share debugging sessions, terminal instances, localhost web apps, voice calls, and more! Developers that join your sessions receive all of their editor context from your environment (e.g. language services, debugging), which ensures they can start productively collaborating immediately, without needing to clone any repos or install any SDKs.
>
> Additionally, unlike traditional pair programming, Visual Studio Live Share allows developers to work together, while retaining their personal editor preferences (e.g. theme, keybindings), as well as having their own cursor. This allows you to seamlessly transition between following one another, and being able to explore ideas/tasks on your own. In practice, this ability to work together and independently provides a collaboration experience that is potentially more natural for many common use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would recommend GitHub, is a great tool. If you like to learn from video, I would recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fk12ELJ9Bww). Or read this [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is **live share**

**Live Share is** an extension for VS Code that enables real-time collaboration between developers. It gives users the ability to share a session with someone else, allowing them to edit code as well as share a sever and debugging session